# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException when deploying jsf2.0 on tomcat "I use the same jdk version"

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm working on **JSF2.0** project, and it was working fine on tomcat. Recently I bought a **Primefaces theme** in order to use it with my project. After I added all the required files, the project was no longer able to deploy on tomcat and even glassfish.

I checked several issues regarding to `catalina.LifecycleException`, but none of them applied to my issue.

Here is the exception I got:

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: try restart tomcat

Comment: I did, I even installed other tomcat instance to try it